# How do dual inverter compressors save power and why can they have variable speeds?

Tags: compressors

As I understand it, most modern air conditions have a rotary compressor with a single rolling piston that's offset from the axis of rotation, causing heavy vibration and limiting RPMs. It then makes sense to me that having two rolling pistons which are 180 degrees offset on the axis of rotation would balance the compressor and significantly reduce vibration, likely allowing for a higher RPM.

But what I don't understand is how this is supposed to also allow for saving energy, and why this is said to allow for variable rotation speed while a single rotary compressor doesn't. (I also don't know why these air conditioners are called "dual inverters" when its really the rolling piston that's dual.)

Can someone explain?

Comment: A dual compressor air conditioner works better if the two compressors have independent speed control.  The prime advantage of "inverter" drive is variable speed control: But when you vary the speed, the ratio of the two compressors should vary also. The prime advantage of single-shaft compressors is "they used to do them that way before independent inverter drives became so cheap"

Comment: Is there a good place to go read about what exactly an inverter drive is?